# No rule to make target when executing make

Tags: makefile, boost-python

With the below makefile I get this answer:

```
>> make makefile_hello_py hello_py.so
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile_hello_py'.
make: *** No rule to make target `hello_py.so'.  Stop.
```

This makefile was modified from [here](http://www.shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/)

```
# location of the Python header files

PYTHON_VERSION = 2.6
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /XXX/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = /YYY/boost/boost_1_54_0
BOOST_LIB = /YYY/boost/boost_bin/lib

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello_py

hello_py.so: hello_py.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python-$(PYTHON_VERSION) -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o hello_py.so

hello_py.o: hello_py.cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c hello_py.cpp
```

Note: The hello_py.cpp file does exist. I've checked twice that I really had on tab at the beginning of each rule. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `makefile_hello_py` is the makefile whose contents you included in the question then you need to use the `-f` argument to tell make that' Your command line is telling make that it is a target to build.

Try `make -f makefile_hello_py hello_py.so`.